# How is the induced morphism $(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)\to (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ defined?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Algebraic Geometry I by Görtz and Wedhorn and have a question concerning the proof of Lemma 1.55. $X$ is an irreducible affine algebraic set and $Z\subseteq X$ is an irreducible closed set. I don't understand the following sentence:

As the inclusion $Z\to X$ is a morphism of affine algebraic sets it induces a morphism $(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)\to (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Can you explain how that induced morphism is defined?

Edit: Here is my approach to prove $\mathcal{O}'_Z(U)\subseteq\mathcal{O}_Z(U)$.

Let $f\in\mathcal{O}'_Z(U)$. For each $x\in U$ we find by definition of $\mathcal{O}'_Z(U)$ an open set $V_x\subseteq X$ ($V$ for short) with $x\in V$ and $g\in\mathcal{O}_X(V)$ such that $f_{\mid U\cap V}=g_{\mid U\cap V}$. The morphism $(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)\to (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ implies that we have $g_{\mid Z\cap V}\in\mathcal{O}_Z(Z\cap V)$. By the first axiom of spaces with functions we get $g_{\mid U\cap V}\in\mathcal{O}_Z(U\cap V)$, hence $f_{\mid U\cap V}\in\mathcal{O}_Z(U\cap V)$. Finally $f$ can be obtained by gluing $f_{\mid U\cap V_x}$ for all $x\in U$. So by the axiom of gluing we get $f\in\mathcal{O}_Z(U)$.

Is that proof correct? If yes, is that the way the authors of the book probably wanted the reader to verify the claim or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your textbook is the one that can be found at https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~blnli/buildings/bag.pdf.

Let $i: Z \to X$ denote the canonical  inclusion map given by $i(z) = z$ for $z \in Z$. For any open subset $U \subset X$ one has a $k$-algebra homomorphism $i^*_U : \mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \mathcal{O}_Z(i^{-1}U) = \mathcal{O}_Z(U \cap Z)$ defined by $i^*_U(f) = f \circ i|_{U \cap Z}$ for any function $f \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ (cf. Definition 1.35(2) on p. 20). The map $i$ together with the collection of the homomorphisms $i^*_U$ for all open $U \subset X$ are the data that define the morphism $(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z) \to (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$. Note that while $i : Z \to X$ is injective, the maps $i^*_U : \mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \mathcal{O}_Z(U\cap Z)$ are usually not injective. If a function $f \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ vanishes at all points $z \in U \cap Z$ then $i^*_U(f)=0$ even though $f$ may not be identically $0$ on $U$. For instance, if $A = k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$ is the coordinate ring of $\mathbb{A}^n(k)$ and $I \subset A$ is the defining ideal of $X$, while $J$ is the defining ideal of $Z$, then the map $i^*_X : \mathcal{O}_X(X) \to \mathcal{O}_Z(Z)$ is simply the quotient map $A/I \to A/J$ with kernel the ideal $J/I$ of $A/I$.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the textbook I'm talking about. I think you meant $i^*_U : \mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \mathcal{O}_Z(i^{-1}U) = \mathcal{O}_Z(U \cap Z)$. But nevertheless, the morphism you are presenting me is a morphism $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to (Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)$ instead of $(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)\to (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, isn't it? I already thought about that one, but it's a morphism in the wrong direction. That's why I'm so confused and posted the question. Anyway, thanks a lot for your extensive answer.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the typo in $\mathcal{O}_Z(U\cap Z)$, I corrected it in my original answer. The morphism is in the right direction, from $Z$ to $X$. Whenever we have a map of sets $f : S \to T$, and a third set $R$ is given, then we have a natural map *in the opposite direction* $f^* : \operatorname{Map}(T,R) \to \operatorname{Map}(S,R)$ defined by $f^*(\phi) = \phi \circ f$ for $\phi \in \operatorname{Map}(T,R)$. There is no obvious way to obtain from $f$ a map $\operatorname{Map}(S,R) \to \operatorname{Map}(T,R)$ unless $f$ is a bijection (in which case we would take $(f^{-1})^*$).

Comment: If $X$ is a fixed irreducible algebraic subset of some affine space, then the collection of the rings $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ where $U$ runs over all Zariski open subsets of $X$, together with the restriction maps $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \mathcal{O}_X(V)$ whenever $V \subset U$, is an example of a *sheaf of rings* on $X$. The 'space with functions' $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is usually termed a *ringed space*. You may wish to compare the definition of a morphism between ringed spaces (Definition 2.29 on p. 55) with the description of the morphism $(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z) \to (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope now I got it. I edited my question and added a proof of $\mathcal{O}'_Z(U)\subseteq\mathcal{O}_Z(U)$. Is it correct?

Comment: Your argument is correct, and at least I can't imagine a shorter one. I must emphasise however that in my answer above I only pointed out how the morphism $(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)\to (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ should be defined. I *did not prove* the statement "for all open subsets $U\subset X$ and all $f\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ the function $i^*_U(f) : U\cap Z \to K$ belongs to $\mathcal{O}_Z(U\cap Z)$" (cf. Definition 1.35(2) on p. 20).

Comment: In order to use the morphism $(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)\to(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ in your argument, you should either quote the more general Proposition 1.44 on p. 22 (for which only a sketch of proof is given) or prove the above statement directly using Definition 1.39 on p. 21.

Comment: How does Prop. 1.44 help me? Is it the (ii)=>(i) direction? So I have to show that for $g\in\Gamma(X)$ we have $g_{\mid Z}\in\Gamma(Z)$. But that's clear since $g$ can be regarded as the image of a polynomial $g'$ under $\pi:k[T_1,\dots,T_n]\to k[T_1,\dots,T_n]/I(X)$. Then $g_{\mid Z}=\pi'(g')$ with $\pi':k[T_1,\dots,T_n]\to k[T_1,\dots,T_n]/I(Z)$.

Comment: This is of course true, but actually you need the implication (i) $\Rightarrow$ (iii). According to Definition 1.28 on p. 16, a morphism between affine algebraic sets is a map given by polynomials, and in our case, we have $i(z) = z = (T_1(z),\ldots,T_n(z))$ for $z \in Z$, so $i$ is already known to be a morphism of affine algebraic sets. In order to deduce that it defines a morphism of spaces with functions $(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z) \to (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, we need (iii). Alternatively, you can use your observation about the map $\Gamma(X) \to \Gamma(Z)$ and the implication (ii) $\Rightarrow$ (iii).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I somehow misread Prop 1.44 and thought item (i) was already "the map $f$ is a morphism of spaces with functions" but that's actually item (iii).

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: In the remaining part of the proof of Lemma 1.55 (where $\mathcal{O}_Z(U)\subseteq\mathcal{O}'_Z(U)$ is shown), does it simplify the proof to choose $h=1$? I don't see why this should not be possible.

Comment: If we can choose $h=1$, this would mean that $f \in \mathcal{O}_Z(U)$ extends to a globally defined function $g \in \Gamma(Z)$, which need not be the case (e.g. if $X = \mathbb{A}^2(k)$, $Z = \{T_1^2-T_2=0\}$, $U = Z\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, then $f = T_1/T_2 \in \mathcal{O}_Z(U)$ does not extend to a function in $\Gamma(Z) \simeq k[T_1]$). As $D(h) = D(h^n)$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$, one could assume $n=1$, but that is hardly a simplification in this case.

Comment: Thx. Again I misread something. This time it was $D(h)\subseteq U$. I only read $x\in D(h)$ and thought $h=1$ will do it. But of course we need $D(h)\subseteq U$ for $f_{\mid D(h)}\in \mathcal{O}_Z(D(h))=\Gamma(Z)_h$.

Comment: This is true, but the real reason, IMHO, is that we want to represent $f$ as a quotient of functions defined on the whole of $Z$, in order to take advantage of the surjectivity of the homomorphism $\Gamma(X)\to\Gamma(Z)$. Luckily, this can be done on open sets of the form $D(h)$, and we can squeeze such a set between any point $x\in Z$ and any neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $Z$. So, the desired representation exists locally around every point. If we could have achieved the same with a larger set, i.e. if $f$ could have been extended beyond $U$, we would have done that, but we can't in general.